# How do I prevent this error during building an extension for jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-extensions

I am finding a difficulty in the following extension [tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html#extension-tutorial) for jupyter labs.
While [building](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html#build-and-install-the-extension-for-development) the tutorial using

```
pip install -ve
```

I have the following error

```
     run(npm_cmd + ["run", build_cmd], cwd=str(abs_path))
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatch_jupyter_builder/utils.py", line 225, in run
      return subprocess.check_call(cmd, **kwargs)
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/bin/jlpm', 'run', 'install:extension']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/bin/python3.10 /home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_editable /tmp/tmpnb1xd5vq
  cwd: /home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The entire error file is also attached here:

```
pip install -ve .
Using pip 22.2.2 from /home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Obtaining file:///home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting hatchling>=1.3.1
    Using cached hatchling-1.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
  Collecting jupyterlab<4.0.0,>=3.4.7
    Using cached jupyterlab-3.4.8-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
  Collecting hatch-nodejs-version
    Using cached hatch_nodejs_version-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
  Collecting editables>=0.3
    Using cached editables-0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
  Collecting packaging>=21.3
    Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Collecting pathspec>=0.10.1
    Using cached pathspec-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Collecting tomli>=1.2.2
    Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
  Collecting pluggy>=1.0.0
    Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Collecting jupyter-server~=1.16
    Using cached jupyter_server-1.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (346 kB)
  Collecting jupyter-core
    Using cached jupyter_core-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
  Collecting ipython
    Using cached ipython-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (752 kB)
  Collecting jupyterlab-server~=2.10
    Using cached jupyterlab_server-2.15.2-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
  Collecting notebook<7
    Using cached notebook-6.4.12-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 MB)
  Collecting jinja2>=2.1
    Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
  Collecting nbclassic
    Using cached nbclassic-0.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 MB)
  Collecting tornado>=6.1.0
    Using cached tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (423 kB)
  Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
    Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
  Collecting Send2Trash
    Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
  Collecting anyio<4,>=3.1.0
    Using cached anyio-3.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
  Collecting nbconvert>=6.4.4
    Using cached nbconvert-7.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (271 kB)
  Collecting prometheus-client
    Using cached prometheus_client-0.14.1-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
  Collecting pyzmq>=17
    Using cached pyzmq-24.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
  Collecting traitlets>=5.1
    Using cached traitlets-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
  Collecting terminado>=0.8.3
    Using cached terminado-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
  Collecting argon2-cffi
    Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
  Collecting jupyter-client>=6.1.12
    Using cached jupyter_client-7.3.5-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
  Collecting nbformat>=5.2.0
    Using cached nbformat-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
  Collecting websocket-client
    Using cached websocket_client-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
  Collecting babel
    Using cached Babel-2.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
  Collecting jsonschema>=3.0.1
    Using cached jsonschema-4.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
  Collecting requests
    Using cached requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
  Collecting json5
    Using cached json5-0.9.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Collecting nest-asyncio>=1.5
    Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
  Collecting ipython-genutils
    Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
  Collecting ipykernel
    Using cached ipykernel-6.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
  Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
    Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
  Collecting backcall
    Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Collecting pexpect>4.3
    Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
  Collecting stack-data
    Using cached stack_data-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
  Collecting pickleshare
    Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
  Collecting decorator
    Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
  Collecting matplotlib-inline
    Using cached matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
  Collecting prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>3.0.1
    Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.31-py3-none-any.whl (382 kB)
  Collecting pygments>=2.4.0
    Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
  Collecting jedi>=0.16
    Using cached jedi-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting notebook-shim>=0.1.0
    Using cached notebook_shim-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Collecting sniffio>=1.1
    Using cached sniffio-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Collecting idna>=2.8
    Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
  Collecting parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
    Using cached parso-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
  Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
    Using cached attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
  Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0
    Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (115 kB)
  Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.2
    Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
  Collecting entrypoints
    Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
  Collecting tinycss2
    Using cached tinycss2-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
    Using cached nbclient-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
  Collecting beautifulsoup4
    Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
  Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
    Using cached pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
  Collecting bleach
    Using cached bleach-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
  Collecting defusedxml
    Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
  Collecting mistune<3,>=2.0.3
    Using cached mistune-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
  Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
    Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting fastjsonschema
    Using cached fastjsonschema-2.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5
    Using cached ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Collecting wcwidth
    Using cached wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
  Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings
    Using cached argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (86 kB)
  Collecting pytz>=2015.7
    Using cached pytz-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
  Collecting psutil
    Using cached psutil-5.9.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (282 kB)
  Collecting debugpy>=1.0
    Using cached debugpy-1.6.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.8 MB)
  Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
    Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
  Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
    Using cached certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
  Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
    Using cached urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
  Collecting executing
    Using cached executing-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Collecting asttokens
    Using cached asttokens-2.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting pure-eval
    Using cached pure_eval-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Collecting six>=1.5
    Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.0.1
    Using cached cffi-1.15.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (441 kB)
  Collecting soupsieve>1.2
    Using cached soupsieve-2.3.2.post1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
  Collecting webencodings
    Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
  Installing collected packages: webencodings, wcwidth, Send2Trash, pytz, pure-eval, ptyprocess, pickleshare, mistune, json5, ipython-genutils, fastjsonschema, executing, backcall, websocket-client, urllib3, traitlets, tornado, tomli, tinycss2, soupsieve, sniffio, six, pyzmq, pyrsistent, pyparsing, pygments, pycparser, psutil, prompt-toolkit, prometheus-client, pluggy, pexpect, pathspec, parso, pandocfilters, nest-asyncio, MarkupSafe, jupyterlab-pygments, idna, entrypoints, editables, defusedxml, decorator, debugpy, charset-normalizer, certifi, babel, attrs, terminado, requests, python-dateutil, packaging, matplotlib-inline, jupyter-core, jsonschema, jinja2, jedi, cffi, bleach, beautifulsoup4, asttokens, anyio, stack-data, nbformat, jupyter-client, hatchling, argon2-cffi-bindings, nbclient, ipython, hatch-nodejs-version, argon2-cffi, nbconvert, ipykernel, notebook, jupyter-server, notebook-shim, jupyterlab-server, nbclassic, jupyterlab
  Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.1 Send2Trash-1.8.0 anyio-3.6.1 argon2-cffi-21.3.0 argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0 asttokens-2.0.8 attrs-22.1.0 babel-2.10.3 backcall-0.2.0 beautifulsoup4-4.11.1 bleach-5.0.1 certifi-2022.9.24 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 debugpy-1.6.3 decorator-5.1.1 defusedxml-0.7.1 editables-0.3 entrypoints-0.4 executing-1.1.1 fastjsonschema-2.16.2 hatch-nodejs-version-0.3.0 hatchling-1.11.0 idna-3.4 ipykernel-6.16.0 ipython-8.5.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.18.1 jinja2-3.1.2 json5-0.9.10 jsonschema-4.16.0 jupyter-client-7.3.5 jupyter-core-4.11.1 jupyter-server-1.19.1 jupyterlab-3.4.8 jupyterlab-pygments-0.2.2 jupyterlab-server-2.15.2 matplotlib-inline-0.1.6 mistune-2.0.4 nbclassic-0.4.5 nbclient-0.7.0 nbconvert-7.2.1 nbformat-5.7.0 nest-asyncio-1.5.6 notebook-6.4.12 notebook-shim-0.1.0 packaging-21.3 pandocfilters-1.5.0 parso-0.8.3 pathspec-0.10.1 pexpect-4.8.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 pluggy-1.0.0 prometheus-client-0.14.1 prompt-toolkit-3.0.31 psutil-5.9.2 ptyprocess-0.7.0 pure-eval-0.2.2 pycparser-2.21 pygments-2.13.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 pyrsistent-0.18.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.4 pyzmq-24.0.1 requests-2.28.1 six-1.16.0 sniffio-1.3.0 soupsieve-2.3.2.post1 stack-data-0.5.1 terminado-0.16.0 tinycss2-1.1.1 tomli-2.0.1 tornado-6.2 traitlets-5.4.0 urllib3-1.26.12 wcwidth-0.2.5 webencodings-0.5.1 websocket-client-1.4.1
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Checking if build backend supports build_editable
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build editable
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Running command pip subprocess to install backend dependencies
  Collecting hatch-jupyter-builder>=0.5
    Using cached hatch_jupyter_builder-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
  Collecting hatchling
    Using cached hatchling-1.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
  Collecting pathspec>=0.10.1
    Using cached pathspec-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
  Collecting packaging>=21.3
    Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
  Collecting tomli>=1.2.2
    Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
  Collecting pluggy>=1.0.0
    Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
  Collecting editables>=0.3
    Using cached editables-0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
  Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
    Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
  Installing collected packages: tomli, pyparsing, pluggy, pathspec, editables, packaging, hatchling, hatch-jupyter-builder
  Successfully installed editables-0.3 hatch-jupyter-builder-0.8.0 hatchling-1.11.0 packaging-21.3 pathspec-0.10.1 pluggy-1.0.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 tomli-2.0.1
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Running command Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml)
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:Running jupyter-builder
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:Building with hatch_jupyter_builder.npm_builder
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:With kwargs: {'build_cmd': 'install:extension', 'npm': ['jlpm'], 'source_dir': 'src', 'build_dir': 'stockWhiz01/labextension'}
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:Installing build dependencies with npm.  This may take a while...
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:> /tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/bin/jlpm install
  yarn install v1.21.1
  info No lockfile found.
  [1/4] Resolving packages...
  warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/apputils > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
  warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/ui-components > @blueprintjs/core > popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
  warning @jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/ui-components > @blueprintjs/core > react-popper > popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
  warning @jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
  warning @jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > verdaccio > request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
  warning @jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > verdaccio > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
  warning @jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > verdaccio > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest-junit > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
  warning @jupyterlab/testutils > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
  [2/4] Fetching packages...
  info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
  info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
  [3/4] Linking dependencies...
  warning "@jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/ui-components@3.4.8" has unmet peer dependency "react@^17.0.1".
  warning "@jupyterlab/application > @lumino/coreutils@1.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
  warning "@jupyterlab/application > @jupyterlab/rendermime > @jupyterlab/codemirror > y-codemirror@3.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "yjs@^13.5.17".
  warning "@jupyterlab/builder > @jupyterlab/buildutils > verdaccio > clipanion@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "typanion@*".
  warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
  warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
  [4/4] Building fresh packages...
  success Saved lockfile.
  Done in 384.66s.
  INFO:hatch_jupyter_builder.utils:> /tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/bin/jlpm run install:extension
  yarn run v1.21.1
  $ jlpm build
  $ jlpm build:lib && jlpm build:labextension:dev
  $ tsc
  $ jupyter labextension build --development True .
  Building extension in .
  /home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:141092
              changeTracker.replaceNode(propertyDeclarationSo
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
      at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
      at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078:15)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:27)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01/node_modules/@jupyterlab/buildutils/lib/ensure-package.js:32:25)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)

  Node.js v18.10.0
  An error occurred.
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['node', '/home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01/node_modules/@jupyterlab/builder/lib/build-labextension.js', '--core-path', '/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging', '/home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01', '--development']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-logmwuri.log
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 177, in prepare_metadata_for_build_editable
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_editable
  AttributeError: module 'hatchling.build' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_editable'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 186, in prepare_metadata_for_build_editable
      whl_basename = build_hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/build.py", line 61, in build_editable
      return os.path.basename(next(builder.build(wheel_directory, ['editable'])))
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatchling/builders/plugin/interface.py", line 136, in build
      build_hook.initialize(version, build_data)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatch_jupyter_builder/plugin.py", line 83, in initialize
      raise e
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatch_jupyter_builder/plugin.py", line 78, in initialize
      build_func(self.target_name, version, **build_kwargs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatch_jupyter_builder/utils.py", line 116, in npm_builder
      run(npm_cmd + ["run", build_cmd], cwd=str(abs_path))
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hatch_jupyter_builder/utils.py", line 225, in run
      return subprocess.check_call(cmd, **kwargs)
    File "/home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-build-env-4een4_o_/overlay/bin/jlpm', 'run', 'install:extension']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/bin/python3.10 /home/savakar/miniconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_editable /tmp/tmpnb1xd5vq
  cwd: /home/savakar/Documents/PROJECTS/JupyterLabExtension/stockWhiz01
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Could you please direct me towards a solution.

--- edit
There is no mention of the hatchling file during `pip freeze` command.

```
flit_core @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/flit-core_1645629044586/work/source/flit_core
idna @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/idna_1663625384323/work
```

whereas during the the install command the first package collected is hatchling.

Comment: It seems like a very recent regression, was also mentioned on https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/setting-up-dev-environment/16145 yesterday.

Comment: What is the version of hatchling when you run `pip freeze`

Comment: The `pip freeze` command returns no package with `hatchling, hatch` infact anything starting with h

Comment: During the [4/4] of yarn, I notice that the command `jupyter labextension build --development True .` is being run on a file having a syntax error. Could that be an issue?